# Multi-threading: How to 'Lock' an Object by One or More Threads

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, shared-memory

I have one 'main' thread that creates an array of objects of class `SlowData`. These objects are relatively slow to manipulate with. This is why, when I initially load them, they are filled with stub data.

Immediately after each object in the array is loaded, I can display the array in the UI. Parallel with that, I initiate the computation over the array. The `SlowDataComputation` object is instructed to report results to the UI (which in turn will visualize the modification of a particular `SlowData` object).

Here's how this would look:

```
void main()
{
  std::vector<SlowData> aData;
  aData.reserve(1000000); // one million instances

  Fast_PopulateVector(aData);

  DataUi aUi;

  SlowDataComputation aCalc;
  aCalc.SetUiCallback(aUi);           // instruct the object to periodically
                                      // report computation results to the UI

  aCalc.Slow_ComputeInSeveralThreads(aData);

  aUi.VisualizeInMessageLoop(aData);  // message loop that exits upon user signal

  if ( aCalc.StillWorking() )
    aCalc.Stop();                     // terminate threads gradually

  // after VisualizeInMessageLoop returns, aData will then be destroyed
}
```

I want `SlowDataComputation` to launch *several* threads, each of which would process a certain segment within the array:

```
class SlowDataComputation
{
  std::vector<SlowData> * myData;
  DataUi                * myUI;

public:
  void Slow_ComputeInSeveralThreads(std::vector<SlowData> & theV)
  {
    myData = &theV;

    size_t aSize = myData->size();
    size_t aNumThreads = 10;
    size_t aBlockSize = aSize / aNumThreads;

    for (size_ti = 0; i < aNumThreads; i++)
    {
      ComputationThread aThr(myData);
      aThr.SetBoundary(i * aBlockSize, (i+1) * aBlockSize);
      aThr.SetUiCallback(myUI);

      aThr.Run();   // process a given segment in the array
    }
  }
};
```

Finally, here's some pseudo-code for the UI:

```
class DataUi
{
  std::vector<SlowData> * myData;

public:
  void VisualizeInMessageLoop()
  {
    Message aMsg;

    while ( HasMessage(aMsg) )
      if (aMsg.Code == Message::MSG_PROGRAM_QUIT)
        SignalQuit();  // next time, HasMessage will return false

    // return from message loop
  }
};
```

**The question is**: how do I secure the destruction of `SlowData` instances so that if *any of the ten* computation threads is currently working with an object, destruction needs to wait until each of these computation threads completes (either because it finished processing or because the `SlowDataComputation::Stop` method was called)? What synchronization primitive is most suitable for this task?

I managed to solve this problem with *one* computation thread. I used Critical Sections. But this solution doesn't scale well for more than one computation threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of your `main` function `join` all your threads with [pthread_join](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/man/pthread_join.txt)
Something like ...

```
  for(t=0; t<NUM_THREADS; t++) {
     rc = pthread_join(thread[t], &status);
     //check rc and status
  }
  //destroy shared data safely. All the threads are done.
```

you don't need to lock the object, which is more expensive. You just need to know that all the threads finished their computation.